# Authorization failed because server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request

Tags: python, oauth, fitbit

I was trying to make a Fitbit Unofficial API according to instructions given in the following link
https://towardsdatascience.com/collect-your-own-fitbit-data-with-python-ff145fa10873
We encountered an error after executing the following code. After entering this code, a link opened to authorize. After clicking allow we got the error saying
"500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidClientError: (invalid_client)"

How do I resolve this?

```
import fitbit
import gather_keys_oauth2 as Oauth2
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
CLIENT_ID = '22CPDQ'
CLIENT_SECRET = '56662aa8bf31823e4137dfbf48a1b5f1'
server = Oauth2.OAuth2Server(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
server.browser_authorize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether the `client_id` you registered there is the same as the one you have mentioned in the code above? It might be the issue.